# Magento2 Get parent image from a simple product (configurable)

Tags: magento2

How can I get parent image from a simple product if the simple product has no base image?

The following code gets the simple product image in a template file.

```
$_imagehelper = $this->helper('Magento\Catalog\Helper\Image');
$productImage = $_imagehelper->init($product, 'category_page_list')->constrainOnly(FALSE)->keepAspectRatio(TRUE)->keepFrame(FALSE)->resize(400)->getUrl();
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want the parent of the simple product you would use the following

```
$product = $_product->getId();

$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$configurableProductResource = $objectManager->create('Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Type\Configurable');

// Get the parent product IDs for the given child product
$parentIds = $configurableProductResource->getParentIdsByChild($product);

if (isset($parentIds[0])) {
    $parentProductId = $parentIds[0];
    
    // Load the parent product
    $productRepository = $objectManager->get('Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface');
    $parentProduct = $productRepository->getById($parentProductId);

    // Check if the child product has an image set
    if ($_product->getImage() !== 'no_selection') {
        // Get the parent product's image
        $parentProductImage = $parentProduct->getImage();
        
        // You can now use $parentProductImage as the parent product's image
        echo "Parent Product Image: " . $parentProductImage;
    }
}
```

This code does the following:

1. Gets the parent product IDs for the given child product using
   $configurableProductResource->getParentIdsByChild($product).
2. Checks if there is a parent product ID in the $parentIds array.
3. If a parent product ID is found, it loads the parent product using the ProductRepositoryInterface.
4. It checks if the child product has an image set by comparing it to 'no_selection'
5. If the child product has an image set, it retrieves the parent
   product's image and stores it in the $parentProductImage variable, which you can use as needed.

Please make sure that you're using the Magento service contracts (like ProductRepositoryInterface) whenever possible instead of directly using the object manager for better code practices and compatibility with future versions of Magento.

Comment: Hi, Ok, that works, but I don't think it's good to use ObjectManager in a template file?

Comment: This is helpful but it would be more useful if it was complete and retrieved the image. Can anyone complete this?

Comment: @ChrisOliver have modified my answer to give you a more accurate answer.

Comment: Thank you @DavaGordon, that looks good.
The way I am wanting to use this is if the child product has no image, then inherit the configurable parent image, if the child product does have an image then use that. So the preference is for a simple product to use it's own image but if there isn't one, to use the parents.
Removing ! from this would achieve that? 
if ($_product->getImage() !== 'no_selection') {

Comment: @ChrisOliver at this point $product = $_product->getId(); you want to check if the simple product has an image so something like if($_product->getImage()) { //return simple image }else { the code from my comment. }

Comment: @DavaGordon I'm using this. It works as expected, thanks. Just wondering if you'd know how to modify it so that configurable child products show their own image if they have one. When I use $imageUrl = $this->imageHelper->init($_product, 'cart_page_product_thumbnail')->getUrl(); to get a product image, if there are two child products of the same configurable parent in the cart, they both show the same simple image rather than their own, even though the product id for each is correct. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I built on the previous answer to get the image url, should this help anyone.

```
// Show Configurable Parent Image
$product = $product->getId();
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$product = $objectManager->create('Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Type\Configurable')->getParentIdsByChild($product);
 if(isset($product[0])){
  $product = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($product);
  $imageBlock =  $block->getLayout()->createBlock('Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct');
  $productImage = $imageBlock->getImage($product, 'cart_page_product_thumbnail');
  $producturl = $product->getProductUrl();
  $productimagehtml = $productImage->toHtml();
    $thumbnail = $productimagehtml;
```